# Leaflet.js draw controls not movable over whole map window area

Tags: javascript, mapping, leaflet, gis, leaflet.draw

I'm using `Leaflet.js` draw controls to make markers and polygons on my map.

When I select the draw controls to place a marker or polygon it follows my mouse as expected on about 80% of my map window, but a large swath of the map window to the upper left corner is not accessible to the draw control.

This diagram shows the map and the x's show the region are where the draw controls cannot go. The draw controls are located in the lower right corner of the window.

```
 _____________________________
|xxxxxxx                      |
|xxxxxxx                      |
|xxxxxxx                      |
|xxxxxxx                      |
|xxxxxxx                      |
|xxxxxxx                      |
|                             |
|                             |
|_____________________________|
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: Without your code and a minimal example that replicates your problem on JSFiddle or Plunker we're just guessing over here.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback iH8. I'll make a fiddle shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the process of trying to replicate the issue in JSFiddle I discovered the problem.

It was due to an invisible `div` which was covering part of the map and therefore blocking the leaflet draw elements.

I was able to quickly identify the offending `div` using a chrome extension called `Div Density`.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/div-density/akhjnfacldhnbhkpmhebkfocmheaicif?hl=en

I'll definitely be using this extension to aid in development and debugging in the future!